# Webhost no carga las imágenes porque llevan tildes o ñ

Tags: laravel, hosting

He subido la aplicación a un hosting gratuito webhost, y tengo el problema que **`cuando se encuentra con una tilde o una 'ñ', no carga la imagen.`**

En localhost las imágenes se cargan perfectamente y desde el filezilla he comprobado que la imagen está donde corresponde y con la sintaxis correcta...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has comprobado desde el servidor (en línea de comandos) que los ficheros están y se ven como deben verse? Puede ser un tema de codificación.

Comment: te he pasado las imágenes para enseñarte que el inspeccionar y el filecilla tienen la misma ruta.

Comment: No con Filezilla, me refiero que lo compruebes desde la línea de comandos

Comment: No tengo ni idea de dónde está la linea de comandos en webhost

Comment: Parece que el host no tiene instalados los idiomas que necesitas. . Ejecuta mediante SSH en el host locale -a.